# Aparición de una especie de "padding-top" al incluir un <p> dentro de un <div>

Tags: div, padding

```css
div{
background-color:blue;}
p{
font-size:100px;
background-color:green;}
```

```html
<body>
<div>
<p>HolaTijuana!</p>
</div>
</body>
```

Al escribir en HTML, un simple div con una etiqueta de parrafo p dentro, el texto aparece con un pequeño espacio en la parte superior, cosa que observo al darle color al contenedor del párrafo con la propiedad "background-color". Gracias al compañero Mikel del foro ahora se que esto es debido a "line-heigth". Efectivamente he modificado dicha propiedad y el texto se aproxima al límite superior de su contenedor. Pero el problema es que lo hace a expensas de salirse del contenedor por abajo. Es posible solucionar esto?

```
<style>
div{
background-color:blue;}
p{
font-size:100px;
line-height: 100 px;
background-color:green;}
</style>

<body>
<div>
<p><HolaTijuana!></p>
</div>
</body>
```

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Es por la propia fuente. Si se quiere reducir el espacio superior entre el borde del contenedor y el texto, habrá que modificar el [espaciado vertical](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) con `line-height`

No se trata del `margin`, ni del `border`, ni del `padding`, que en el siguiente ejemplo se encuentran a 0.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <title>Plantilla</title>
    <style>
      * {margin: 0px; border: 0px; padding: 0px; font-size: 100px;}
      div {background-color: blue;}
      p {font-size: 100px; background-color: green;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hola<br/>Tijuana</p>
    <div>Hola<br/>Tijuana</div>
    <p style="line-height: .8;">Hola<br/>Tijuana</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Saludos.

Comment: No hay padding como tal.... Es el tamaño de la propia fuente. Si se selecciona el texto se puede apreciar. En el primer div y primer párrafo el line-height es el normal, Es el último párrafo con line-height: .8 donde se puede observar como se reducen los espacios usados por la fuente.

Comment: Perdona no me supe explicar, a lo que voy es que al reproducir el ejercicio de quien pregunta yo no alcanzo a notar lo que el dice

Comment: Yo tampoco noto diferencia al reproducir el ejercicio de quien pregunta. No encuentro ningún padding visualmente y menos en código

Comment: Hola Mikel. Gracias por tu respuesta. En tu ultimo parrafo, tal y como comentas, al modificar la propiedad "line-height" se elimina el espacio superior, pero a precio de que el texto se salga del contenedor por abajo. Por otro lado, curiosamente en tu primer parrafo, aunque no modificas dicha propiedad, el texto queda perfecto pues esta dentro del contenedor y sin espacios por arriba o por abajo. He intentado repetirlo usando tu mismo codigo y a mi si que me aparece el espacio superior.